# Equivalent lsof -i in Solaris

Tags: linux, unix, command, solaris, equivalent

I have a fast question. I want to know what is the `losf -i` equivalent command in a Solaris system.

I only want to show the files with network connection.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a shell script that list all processes having open TCP or UDP ports on Solaris, you can limit it to a given port number by passing it as an argument:

```
pfiles /proc/* 2>/dev/null | nawk -v port=$1 '
    /^[0-9]/ { cmd=$2; type="unknown"; continue }
    $1 == "SOCK_STREAM" { type="tcp" }
    $1 == "SOCK_DGRAM" { type="udp" }
    $2 ~ "AF_INET" { if((port!="")&&($5!=port)) continue;
                      if(cmd!="") { printf("%s\n",cmd); cmd="" }
                      printf("    %s:%s/%s\n",$3,$5,type); }'
```

Note: As documented in the warning section of the [`pfiles` manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/pfiles-1.html), it is not recommended to run this command on a heavily loaded production system with a time sensitive process running as deadlocks or crashes might happen.

Note #2: The previous warning doesn't apply to the last update of Solaris (Oracle Solaris 11.4) because `pfiles` no more suspend the monitored process(es). It now just uses ad hoc /proc pseudo files.

Comment: Can I do it in just one line?? Thank you

Comment: Sure, make it a shell function or a shell script and you'll be able to call it with one single command line.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do it. :S

Comment: Something like `mkdir ~/Functions;cat >~/Functions/myLsof <<%function myLsof() { pfiles /proc/* ... ,type); }' % ; export FPATH=~/Functions` Just make sure the % appears in a different line. Feel free to ask a new question by itself if this is unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately I've seen cases where running `pfiles` on a process would crash that process. The reason is that `pfiles` temporarily halts the process in order to inspect it. I would think that 99.9% of all processes are immune to this but a process which is very 'time sensitive' may not like it. It may have been an odd case but it was reproducible, i.e. you could crash the process *every time* just by running `pfiles` on it. You've been warned!

Comment: @nolan6000 indeed, although I would say more like 99.99999+ are immune. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

As of Solaris 11.2 this type of information is now available directly in the [netstat](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36871/netstat-1m.html) command (`-u` option) so you don't have to use the `pfiles` hack for the purpose or use the `lsof` tool. Personally I've always wondered why this information could not be part of the `netstat` output so glad to see that'll finally be the case.

There's a [nice blog from Oracle on the topic](https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/entry/solaris_11_2_user_pid).

(caveat: at the time of writing v11.2 is in beta but fully disclosed as to the contents / new features)

Answer (score 1):

you can try pfiles,fuser. you can install lsof on solaris.

http://andriigrytsenko.net/2010/08/lsof-installation-on-solaris-10/